# How can I extract arabic express from an arabic text?

Tags: c#, winforms, arabic

i have a project that i must extract Arabic token from an Arabic text 
how can i extract these tokens from a text.
with the code below i browse the file and show it in a text box and i want to extract the token from the file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        stropen = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(stropen);

    }
}
```

**Update**

Let me explain the problem.i have an arabic text like the text below. الْحَمْدُ للّه‏ِِ الَّذی عَلا فی تَوَحُّدِهِ وَدَنا فی تَفَرُّدِهِ وَجَلَّ فی سُلْطانِهِ وَعَظُمَ فی أَرْکانِهِ، وَأَحاطَ بِکُلِّ شَیْءٍ عِلْما وَهُوَ فی مَکانِهِ، وَقَهَرَ جَمیعَ الْخَلْقِ بِقُدْرَتِهِ وَبُرْهانِهِ، حَمیدا لَمْ‏یَزَلْ، مَحْمُودا لا یَزالُ وَمَجیدا لا یَزُولُ، وَمُبْدِئا وَمُعیدا وَکُلُّ أَمْرٍ إلَیْهِ یَعُودُ. in my program i show a text in a text box .And i want to Gauging the text and find tokens like "لْ" .not "ل" but a sign above it. i am a beginner in c# . thank u.

Comment: You need to define concept of "Arabic token" before this question can be answered. Side note: don't use signature of any kind in your posts - update your user info instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know arabic script but maybe you can try something based on the following:

You can loop through all characters in a string with a simple foreach loop. Then you can inspect the "Unicode category" of that character (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz49h034.aspx)). If I understand you correctly, you want the "NonSpacingMark" category.

Some sample code:

```
string s = " وَجَلَّ فی ";
foreach (char c in s)
{
    Console.Write(c);
    Console.WriteLine(Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "extract", but assuming the text in the file is unicode-encoded, you basically just extract the token the way you would extract any token.

For example, you can use the various [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods, including [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which searches for a particular substring. You can also use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which are designed to "extract tokens".

If your text file is not unicode-encoded, you have to use the [`File.ReadAllText` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an `Encoding`.